# Mocking ES6 Class Modules exported as objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocking, jestjs

Considering the example below

```
//AuthenticatorService.js
const UserService = require("./UserService");
class AuthenticatorService{
   constructor(){
      //Some initialisation
   }
//Some methods
}
module.exports = new AuthenticatorService();

//UserService.js
class UserService{
   constructor(){
     //Again some initialisations
   }
}
module.exports = new UserService();
```

So when I try to mock the UserService class in my `AuthenticatorService.spec.js` file the constructor of the *UserService* is getting executed as it is being exported in that way. But I don't want that to be executed. Is it possible to mock the *UserService* module inside `AuthenticatorService.spec.js` file without invoking its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to do this.

E.g.

`UserService.js`:

```js
class UserService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('initialize UserService');
  }
  hello() {
    console.log('user hello real implementation');
  }
}
module.exports = new UserService();
```

`AuthenticatorService.js`:

```js
const userService = require('./UserService');

class AuthenticatorService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('initialize AuthenticatorService');
  }
  hello() {
    userService.hello();
  }
}

module.exports = new AuthenticatorService();
```

`AuthenticatorService.test.js`:

```js
const authenticatorService = require('./AuthenticatorService');
const userService = require('./UserService');

jest.mock('./UserService', () => {
  return { hello: jest.fn() };
});

describe('62967707', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    userService.hello.mockImplementationOnce(() => console.log('user hello mocked implementation'));
    authenticatorService.hello();
    expect(userService.hello).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62967707/AuthenticatorService.test.js (12.636s)
  62967707
    ✓ should pass (11ms)

  console.log
    initialize AuthenticatorService

      at new AuthenticatorService (stackoverflow/62967707/AuthenticatorService.js:5:13)

  console.log
    user hello mocked implementation

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/62967707/AuthenticatorService.test.js:13:60)

-------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                     | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 AuthenticatorService.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.703s
```

As you can see in the logs, the real constructor of `UserService` will not execute. And we mocked `hello` method of the `UserService` class's instance.